# Alternative to Piped-/InputOutputStream

Tags: java, audio-player

I have an audio player with uses an PipedOutputStream for buffering the input of the data and a PipedInput for the actual playing. Sometimes the player pauses, but there is still data to buffer. If the buffer is now full, the writing-thread will block indefinitely.

Is there a fast alternative, which supports a timeout on write or another solution?

Comment: Does: [Java Tutorial - Playing Streaming Sampled Audio](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/PlayingStreamingSampledAudio.htm) help you? I believe you can manage the buffer yourself.

Comment: the data comes over network and is faster than the playing, so i have 2 threads.

Comment: You don't need two threads or the pipes at all. Just play directly from the network.

Comment: i get an array of bytes a few times a second, i need to store them anywhere before playing. I get them from a 3rd party library, which first has to do things like authorisation/emcryption etc.

Comment: So? Play them as you get them, as fast as they arrive.

Comment: they arrive faster than the playing, i buffer up to half a song. I am unable to block since it would render my application useless. When i'm block I can't process other events like play/pause/stop

Comment: Just an FYI, if you play them on different machines, they might not be in sync. Usually that doesn't matter, I don't know if it does for you or not? That said, one way to solve this might be to send the bytes only a few seconds ahead of when they should actually be played, that way the buffer never gets too big. By simulating playing the audio on the server for example.

Comment: thank you for reading everything...the buffering is intended. There are events which handle jumping (by flushing the buffer), pause/play etc. the problem is it is single threaded, all i get is an event which may contain audio-data or commands. the protocol is also not under my control :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is spf4j which contains alternative implementation for PipedInput/OuputStream. I have been experiencing same issue and resolved with it.

The root cause of the problem is that the pipedinputstream checks the liveness of writer (the thread calling write from pipiedoutputstream) in read method everytime.
So the writer finishes early, then read would throw exception and finish read loop with unread data remaining